# Next.JS production build sub link view source not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, build, next.js

I am working on Next.js application, i out my build and i put the out on local server folder, everything is fine when i'm navigate via links, i try to navigate the page directly with url route link it show 404 page not found,

Here is my config.js

```
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'

export const server = dev ? 'http://localhost:3000/next_js' : 'http://localhost/next_js'
```

if i hit the link of landing page in URL it show exact result, but i try to change route name with params and those on URL show 404 error, if i track those on page links it show exact result i don't know why it happen,

but the same approach perfectly working on dev server http://localhost:3000/next_js

i'm really stuck with that,

anybody know how to resolve this issue ?

Comment: How are you serving the static folder?

Comment: i just build the out folder, after i paste that out folder in my local server html folder,
i just include basename of my app in next.config.js module.exports = {
    basePath: '/next_js'
  }

Comment: But what are you using as your local server to serve the `out` folder?

Comment: localhost/next_js is my landing page; localhost/next_js/article/[id] to view individual article

Comment: http://products.hitasoft.in/next_js this my app root path, this link working fine while i refreshing the page, but i try to hit the direct URL http://products.hitasoft.in/next_js/article/2 of sub link it show url not found response..